# Center CSS Button with width auto

Tags: css, button, center

I want to have a button with `width:auto;` and `display:block;`. This button should be centered with `margin:0 auto`. But if I take all together, it will not work.

What am I doing wrong?

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>asd</title>
</head>
<body>
I am an example content and I should be above the button. I want to have an auto width and being centered
<style type="text/css">
    .btn{
            color:black;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height:14px;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin:0 auto;
            height:14px;
            display:block;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color:red;
            padding:15px;
            text-decoration:none;   
    }
</style>
<a class="btn">helloworld</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Live example here: http://jsbin.com/osOyAyi/1/edit

Comment: I'm confused what is the issue?

Comment: @cloudcoder2000 You example is finde, but I want to have a width auto and not 50px.

Comment: @Ishan Jain, why you posted this code? It´s nothing else than what I´ve posted. I´m searching a solution without a fixed with, without to add another element and with display:block!

Answer (score 8):

You can use `inline-block` instead of `block`:

```
body {
    text-align:center;
}
.btn{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

The demo **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yrUa/1/)**

Another option use `display:table`, with this the margin auto can work:

```
.btn {
   display:table;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The demo **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yrUa/5/)**

Comment: That works, except when there are other elements in the document that might be affected by having the `body` at `text-align: center`. You could apply the same styles to a container instead of the body, but this just adds extra, unnecessary complexity.

Comment: But is better that instead of delete the `width:auto` like in your answer :)

Comment: Oh.. yeah doing width in fixed px can be problematic. You're right.

Comment: @julesdude that's the only way you can center the content and have an auto width changing the display property with one of the two options....

Comment: @julesdude you can have this in a new line with `inline-block` and pseudo-selectors `:after and :before`

Comment: @Danko Thank you very much. display:table solved my problem. I´ve only tested it with FF V26, don´t know how it looks inside a cross browser test

Comment: Ok, is there a bug fix for IE7 available?

Answer (score 0):

If you set it as `width: auto`, then the element will fill the entire screen. So it is centered, but you can't tell since it's taking up the entire screen. Simply change `width: auto` to a fixed width like `50px` or `30%` and it will center properly. [Demo](http://jsbin.com/osOyAyi/2/edit)

If you have variable content, then get rid of the `height: 15px` and it will work. It will also look a little nicer with `width: 65%`. [Demo](http://jsbin.com/osOyAyi/4/edit)

Comment: @LJ-C You're right; with `50px` the text doesn't even fit in the box! However, that doesn't really pertain to the question, as it is still centered....

Comment: Hi, but I´d like to have a variable content so it´s not a solution for me to have a fixed with

Comment: I´m searching a solution without a fixed with, without to add another element and with display:block! (so the button appears in a new line)

Comment: @julesdude do you think `display:block` is the only way to appear in a new line?

Comment: @cloudcoder2000 display:table solved my problem. I didn´t wanted to have any width, whether percentage or pixel. Only one line and the button should change the width depending on the two or three words inside of it.

Comment: @julesdude I'm glad you solved your problem. Now, make sure to upvote and accept Danko's answer. :)